# Why service is not reading AWS Secrets Manager in AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, aws-secrets-manager

I am deploying a springboot2.5.0 gradle project in AWS ECS, where it has to read AWS Secrets Manager on startup. I have written this 2 files to read the Secrets Manager in aws. But the service is still failing to read the values from the manager. Any pointers will help.
The Error in ECS Container

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'moa.aws.secrets.oidc.introspectUrl' in value "${moa.aws.secrets.oidc.introspectUrl}"
```

The 2 files

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SecretsManagerBootstrapConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator awsSecretsManager(
            @Value("${aws.secrets:}") final String[] allowedSecrets) {
        return new SecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator(allowedSecrets);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator;
import org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.CompositePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.EnumerablePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class SecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator.class);
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    private String[] allowedSecrets;

    public SecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator(
            final String[] secrets) {
        this.allowedSecrets = secrets;
        for (String secret : allowedSecrets) {
             LOGGER.debug("allowed secrets ::===> " + secret);
            
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param environment the current Environment
     * @return a PropertySource or null if there is none
     * @throws IllegalStateException if there is a fail fast condition
     */
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {

        final CompositePropertySource propertySource = new CompositePropertySource("aws-secrets-store");

        final MutablePropertySources sources = ((AbstractEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources();
        for (String secret : allowedSecrets
        ) {
            StreamSupport.stream(sources.spliterator(), false)
                    .filter(ps -> ps instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
                    .map(ps -> ((EnumerablePropertySource) ps).getPropertyNames())
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .distinct()
                    .filter(prop -> (prop.contains(secret)))
                    .forEach(prop -> {
                        propertySource.addPropertySource(new MapPropertySource(secret, jsonToMap(prop, environment.getProperty(prop))));

                    });
        }

        return propertySource;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(final String name, String jsonString) {
    
        try {
            final Map<String, Object> map = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
            return map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(
                            Collectors.toMap(
                                    e -> name.replaceAll("/", ".") + '.' + e.getKey(),
                                    Map.Entry::getValue
                            ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing your Secret Manager code in the above code examples. How are you invoking this AWS Service? The best practice (from a Java app) is to use the [Secret Manager V2 Java API](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager). You can use this Java API from within a Spring app. To obtain a secret from this service - use Java V2 code like this:

```
package com.example.secrets;

//snippet-start:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.SecretsManagerException;
//snippet-end:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 *https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetSecretValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetSecretValue  <secretName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    secretName - the name of the secret (for example, tutorials/MyFirstSecret). \n";

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String secretName = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SecretsManagerClient secretsClient = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getValue(secretsClient, secretName);
        secretsClient.close();
    }

    //snippet-start:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.main]
    public static void getValue(SecretsManagerClient secretsClient,String secretName) {

        try {
            GetSecretValueRequest valueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder()
                .secretId(secretName)
                .build();

            GetSecretValueResponse valueResponse = secretsClient.getSecretValue(valueRequest);
            String secret = valueResponse.secretString();
            System.out.println(secret);

        } catch (SecretsManagerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[secretsmanager.java2.get_secret.main]
}
```